# BigQuery can't create view with union tables containing TIMESTAMP fields

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to create a view grouping several daily tables with same schema. The view creation fails on all TIMESTAMP fields with the following error:

> Invalid field name "the_field.usec". Fields must contain only
>   letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore,
>   and be at most 128 characters long

Note that the original field doesn't contain the .usec suffix.

A workaround is to wrap all TIMESTAMP fields with the FORMAT_UTC_USEC() function, but the field is then no longer a TIMESTAMP, it becomes an INTEGER.

Comment: have exactly the same problem

Comment: I had to convert the field to a String(Timestamp) to get it to work and then convert again on the other-side when querying the view.

Comment: are you still having this problem? sorry for overlooking the question until now!

Comment: Just ran into this problem. Converting it to an int or string works but is a bit hacky.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write as:

`select FORMAT_UTC_USEC(timestamp) as timestamp ...`

Also you need to de-reference nested record type fields for views:

`SELECT utm.campaign as utm_campaign ...`

Answer (score 0):

I am happy to say, that this long standing problem has been fixed, and you can build arbitrary views involving tables with TIMESTAMP fields (including union, join etc).